# Prettier removes the space between html tag and text

Tags: vue.js, prettier

I have installed a vue project using the cli, with eslint and prettier configured, however prettier does things I don't want. I want to have a | between the two  tags, but when I save prettier removes the space between the tag and |.
how can I fix this.
here is the code:
notice the | on line two, and the space before it is removed by prettier.

```
<div id="nav">
  <router-link :to="{name: 'event-list'}">List</router-link>|
  <router-link :to="{name: 'event-create'}">Create</router-link>
</div>
<router-view />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem you're having is that Prettier omitting the whitespace is causing your rendered HTML to come out missing the space:

```
List| Create
```

Then you can wrap your `|` in a `<span>` tag, which will automatically add a space between the elements when rendered. Prettier shouldn't complain about it once it's wrapped.

```html
<div id="nav">
  <router-link :to="{name: 'event-list'}">List</router-link>
  <span>|</span>
  <router-link :to="{name: 'event-create'}">Create</router-link>
</div>
<router-view />
```

You also may want to check out the [HTML Whitespace Sensitivity](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#html-whitespace-sensitivity) setting in your Prettier config, and their [writeup on whitespace-sensitive formatting in HTML](https://prettier.io/blog/2018/11/07/1.15.0.html#whitespace-sensitive-formatting).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I added a &nbsp; before the |, however, I needed to know how to get rid of that prettier configuration